# Copy SSRS Subscriptions from one SSRS server to another

Tags: ssrs

I am having to migrate reports and subscriptions from one SSRS server to another. I have already migrated the RDL and Datasources. I only have the subscription information to move. I am trying to use the ReportingServicesTools (https://github.com/microsoft/ReportingServicesTools) and an example from here http://wragg.io/managing-sql-server-reporting-services-subscriptions-with-powershell/ to accomplish this.  I exported the subscription information using Get-RsSubsctiption | Export-RsSubscriptionXml to a file.

I am trying to import it using Import-RsSubscriptionXml | Set-RsSubscription. When this executes, I get no messages, error or informational. When I look in the SSRS database, I don't see the subscription.

Here are the commands:

```
Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri 'http://sql2017/reportserver' -RsItem '/Cooperative Technologies/1035/1035YellowPages/Billing Reports/LookupActivityReport' | Export-RsSubscriptionXml "c:\users\logsdone\desktop\SSRS Subscriptions\1.xml"

Import-RsSubscriptionXml "c:\users\logsdone\desktop\SSRS Subscriptions\1.xml"  -ReportServerUri 'http://sql2017/reportserver'  | Set-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri 'http://sql2017/reportserver'
```

Thanks for any suggestions or additional documentation or examples.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

you are using [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ReportingServicesTools/0.0.6.5) PowerShell module from the gallery.

You need to use `Copy-RsSubscription` if the subscription on the destination does not already exist. `Set-RsSubscription` updates only already created subscriptions.

```
Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri 'http://sql2017/reportserver' -RsItem '/Cooperative Technologies/1035/1035YellowPages/Billing Reports/LookupActivityReport' | Export-RsSubscriptionXml "c:\users\logsdone\desktop\SSRS Subscriptions\1.xml"
Import-RsSubscriptionXml "c:\users\logsdone\desktop\SSRS Subscriptions\1.xml"  -ReportServerUri 'http://sql2017/reportserver'  | Copy-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri 'http://sql2017/reportserver' -RsItem '/Cooperative Technologies/1035/1035YellowPages/Billing Reports/LookupActivityReport'
```